# Will bread yeast restart stuck brewery in a bag

Tags: first-time-brewer

Building up to my first home brewing I purchased a muntons brewery in a bag session IPA. (On special from Aldi seemed like a steal).

I followed all instructions to the letter keeping everything sterile. Instructions were; add 4 pints of warm water to dissolve one, add dried yeast packet, top up with cold water, leave to ferment, move somewhere cold after a week. In the beginning it was bubbling away and seemed to be fermenting just fine. This continued until the last week when it stopped inflating the bag - I initially assumed it was due to the process coming to an end.

Big excitement on day 30, I crack open my beer, pull off a big glass of sediment and discard it. I then pull a 1/4 of a pint. It smells wrong, tasting it I discover it is sweet and unfermented. I’m crestfallen.

I think it’s due to the dried yeast being faulty. So I took 250ml of the liquid, 250ml of warm water, added 2x7g of dried baking yeast, and a couple of spoons of auger to make a yeast starter. Once it was bubbling and I had left the beer next to the radiator to warm up slightly I added it.

After a few hours it appears to be frothing, and smells slightly like its fermenting.

The question is - is there any point in this experiment and can anyone suggest a time scale?

Comment: Are you sure the instructions said to top it up with **warm** water? Not **cold** water?

Answer (score 3):

Bread yeast will do the trick fast, probably within 2 days.  But, will end up tasting like bread.

Might be better next time to just buy your own yeast.  US-05 is extremely reliable for just about any beer style.

Cheers.

Comment: For tasting like a bread — not necessarily so. And while US-05 are great, I'd only recommend them for pale styles with low to moderate gravity. And they will not give honest results in traditional British or Belgian recipes. Tasty, yes, but far from the style.